# Change Bootstrap Version In Big Laravel Project

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

Hey Guys I have A big Laravel Project And The project Bootstrap version Is 3
I Want To Change It . How I can do it?

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways to change the Bootstrap version in a Laravel project. One way is to edit the composer.json file and change the version number in the require section. Another way is to edit the config/app.php file and change the version number in the providers section.